# Multiple QR Code Detection of the Same type in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, zxing.net

I am making a qr code reader that pulls qr codes from the webcam video feed using zxing.net the basic code is the following:

```
Bitmap unresized = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
Bitmap newFrame = new Bitmap(unresized, 640, 500);
if (newFrame != null)
{
    BarcodeReader barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();
    var options = new DecodingOptions
    {
        PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat>
    {
        BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
    },
        TryHarder = true
    };
    barcodeReader.Options = options;
    Result[] results = barcodeReader.DecodeMultiple((Bitmap)newFrame);
    if (results != null && results.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
```

also this:

```
if (!detectedQRCodes.ContainsKey(result.Text))
    {
        CodeInfo Code = new CodeInfo();
        Code.Content = result.Text;
        Code.Format = result.BarcodeFormat;
        Code.RotationAngle = rotationAngle;
        Code.MidPoint = midPoint;
        Code.Points = points;
        detectedQRCodes.Add(Code.Content, Code);
        qrCodeDataTable.Rows.Add(result.Text, result.BarcodeFormat.ToString(), angle, midPointString);
    }
    else // if the code was detected before
    {
        detectedQRCodes[result.Text].RotationAngle = rotationAngle;
        detectedQRCodes[result.Text].MidPoint = midPoint;
        detectedQRCodes[result.Text].Points = points;
        DataRow existingRow = qrCodeDataTable.Rows.Find(result.Text);
        existingRow["RotationAngle"] = angle;
        existingRow["MidPoint"] = midPointString;
    }
}
```

so basically it's saving and printing QR code different elements to a datagridview however I want to do the same for the QR codes that have the same content but are in different locations in the same frame as well. So my question would be does ZXing recognize the multiple instances of the same QR code and if it does how can I store and track them as different objects?

Comment: this doesnt help? https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/how-to/read-multiple-barcodes/

Comment: My problem is about tracking them not detecting them I am trying to track their positions in each frame so imagine 6 of the same type of barcode in one frame. The code needs to somehow save them individually an able to refer to their positions when needed. I was distinguishing them by content but for the codes with the same content that solution doesn't help.

Comment: maybe I am missing something... but reading the barcodes/qrcodes will give you a `BarcodeResult` object - this object does have properties `Height`, `Width`, `X1`, `X2`, `Y1`, `Y2` so it will tell you exactly where those results are - is that what you are refering to as tracking? are the information given by `BarcodeResult` insufficient? - https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/object-reference/api/IronBarCode.BarcodeResult.html

Comment: I am aware, but I am currently finding and storing barcode information in real-time from a video feed and then I'm moving a robotic arm to that location. The problem is I am dividing the barcode info into two possible outcomes which are: already detected ones which I  am updating their position info in the next frame. And newly introduced ones which I am saving as new codes. However, since  I am differentiating those with their content. And when multiple codes with the same content appear I cannot track them in the video feed individually since their content are the same.

Comment: So I need to track and save each code that appears in the video feed regardless of their content while decoding them simultaneously. Foe example when exactly the same QR codes appear in the video feed let's say tagged 1,2,3 the program needs to know which one is the 1st and track it separately from the other two.

Comment: sorry, I still don't quite understand the issue at hand - if you read all qrcodes in each frame and check the co-cordinates and position of each qrcode IMHO you can track them - to know if it is the same qrcode of the previous frame make an assumption how fast a qrcode could possible move between two frames eg. frame 1 qrcode is at x1=10, y1=10 on frame2 it is x1=20, y1=20 than it is the same qrcode but it moved sligthly to the right and bottom but if x1=200,y1=200 it is a new qrcode in a new position

Comment: My thoughts exactly! I was just wondering if there is a library or something for calculations like this that might perform the calculations better than the stuff that I'll write.